# upload image to firebase storage directly from express-fileupload

Tags: firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image I got via `express-fileupload` directly to firebase storage. My current approach is to first save the image from express-fileupload, then upload it to firebase storage and then delete it.
Is there a way to directly pass the result of the `express-fileupload` package to the firebase storage, so I don't have to save the file locally?

Comment: Where do you execute the business logic using `express-fileupload`? In one of your Node.js server?

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show the code you have now that doesn't work the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself ...
the express-fileupload file class provides a 'data' attribute, which can simply be passed into storage.upload("name.png", file.data)